# The best way to map correlation matrix from [-1, 1] space to [0, 1] space

Tags: statistics

SO is warning me my question is likely to be closed, I hope they're wrong :)

My question: let you have a correlation matrix; you would like correlations which are next to 1 and -1 go towards 1, while those next to 0 stay there.

The simplest way is to use absolute values, e.g. if `Rho` is you correlation matrix then you will use `abs(Rho)`.

Is there any way which is theoretically more correct than the one above?

As an example: what if I use Normal p.d.f. instead of absolute value?

```
Adjusted Rho = N(Rho, mu = 0, sigma = stdev(Rho))
```

where `N` is the Normal p.d.f. function.

Have you any better way?

What are strengths and weaknesses of each method?

Thanks,

Comment: I suggest asking that at stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you, I'll do. Then moderation could cancel this question, if they think it's non appropriate to SO :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
x <- runif(min = -1, max = 1, n = 100)
tr <- (x - min(x))/diff(range(x))
plot(x)
points(tr, col = "red")
```

You could also use a logit link function that guarantees the values to be between 0 and 1. But given that you're limited to values between -1 and 1, you would get only values in the range of ~[0.3, 1].

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Roman. Your method looks like linear interpolation. I'm not expert in statistics, could you please explain me what are strenghts and weaknesses of: absolute value, Normal p.d.f., your method? Thank you so much.

Comment: @JohnGay, maybe you should open up a new question on that at crossvalidated.com.